# Why not close row?

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I output data from atabase in table.

In result table created with next code:

```
while($i=$res2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $a++;
    $t2.='
    <tr>
    <td>'.$a.'</td>
    <td>'.date_format(new DateTime($i['date']),'d.m.Y').'</td>
    ';

    if($valid!='id'){
        $t2.='
        <td>'.$partner.'</td>
        ';
    }

    $t2.='
    <td>'.$http_referer.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$t1='
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="column_th_number">№</th>
<th>Date</th>
';

if($valid!='id'){
    $t1.='
    <th>Partner</th>
    ';
}


$t1.='
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspane="2">
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
$t3='
</tbody>
</table>
';
echo $t1.$t2.$t3;
```

but in the result I see that last row was not closed (see image):

[image: test image]

Tell me please why last row was not closed?

And how can I make this right?

Comment: @sevenseacat really? you dont see all ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks ALL.*

*Error was with colspan(value does not match the number of columns).*

*Thanks all for help*

Answer (score 3):

```
<td>'.date_format(new DateTime($i['date']),'d.m.Y').'</td>
if($valid!='id'){
```

replace with

```
<td>'.date_format(new DateTime($i['date']),'d.m.Y').'</td>'; <--- end the string here
if($valid!='id'){
```

Comment: no no, not it( i make error in code question). not it error. im update question.

Comment: why not show us the source code? I mean view source!

Comment: you really think that you need see connect with atabase and all select from her? you can see all code on http://pastebin.com/hgTp1E08

Comment: oh sorry, you misunderstood me. I told you to right click in browser->select view soruce.. which would show you the html page which browser has recieved. It helps you to debug the code easily

Comment: thanks) but IM SORRY bsecose i stuped. Error was with colspan(value does not match the number of columns). Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

you missed `';`

```
<td>'.$a.'</td>
<td>'.date_format(new DateTime($i['date']),'d.m.Y').'</td>';
if($valid!='id'){
```

Comment: not it( i make error in code question). not it error. im update question.

Comment: thanks) but IM SORRY bsecose i stuped. Error was with colspan(value does not match the number of columns). Thanks for help